# Are there any rules to remember nouns / adjectives that are related to verbs?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, nouns

I am having a real trouble remembering vocabulary where a noun or adjective is related to a verb (or vice versa).

**Example 1**

Verb tagliare = to cut.

Conjugation taglio = I cut.

Conjugation taglia = he/she/it cuts; you (formal) cut.

Noun taglio = cut.

Noun taglia = size.

Here one noun is the same as the conjugated verb of first person singular. The other noun (totally different meaning but still vaguely related to the verb) takes the form of conjugated verb of third person singular.

**Example 2**

Verb scaricare = to unload, etc.

Conjugation scarico = I unload.

Conjugation scarica = he/she/it unloads; you (formal) unload.

Adjective scarico =  unloaded.

Noun scarica = shot / discharge.

Here the adjective takes the form of first person singular, and the noun takes the form of third person singular.

**Question**

I am having a tough time remembering these differences, e.g. the difference of meanings of scarico from scarica. One letter different and totally different meanings. Same with taglio and taglia.

And there is no pattern either, as seen in the examples.

What’s going on here and how can I get this under control?

Comment: It may be even worse than this: there is often more than one noun from the same root, with similar or different meanings. Just to keep to one of your examples, _scarica_ means indeed “shot/discharge”, but you also have _scaricamento_, meaning more or less “unloading”. So you have both _affrancamento_ and _affrancatura_, both _annullo_ and _annullamento_. And even when just one suffix won, it is often an effect of chance, and perhaps of a tendency to diversify: (1/2)

Comment: for instance _ampliamento_ (from _ampliare_), _abitazione_ (from _abitare_), _abbozzo_ (from _abbozzare_), all of them from first-conjugation verbs. So, there is not any pattern or rule, and one has to learn them gradually. (Even we Italians happen to have doubts, say, between some forms in _-mento_ or _-zione_!)  (2/2)

Comment: I see now that my comment addresses perhaps a slightly different issue than your question, but I hope it is useful all the same.

Comment: Finally, _scarica_ is the feminine form of the adjective _scarico_, as well as the noun you have found.

Comment: @DaG, yes your last comment is very valid. The feminine form of the adjective 'scarico' makes matters even worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't get this under control**

I don't know if it is your case but very often people learning a foreign language for the first time are shocked by how *illogical* it is. It seems like the prepositions are used at random, words have seemingly incompatible meanings and everyone just tells you you have to memorize all this stuff. Of course they do not realize that the rules of their native tongue are just as illogical, if not more.

Story time: my mother is learning English. It is her first time really dedicating time to a foreign language and she is sometimes demoralized by the same problems you have. Why, for example, *lead* may mean both *lead an army* and *a lead seal* (yes, I know they're pronounced differently, but it doesn't help reading, doesn't it?). And why does *can* mean both *potere* and *lattina*?

So, what's the solution? Giving up? No. The answer is **reading**. Reading a lot. Human brains are amazing at pattern recognition and if you see a word  enough in various contexts you will learn how to use it and what are the possible nuances of meanings.

I am afraid there are no simple rules. You'll have to see many, many examples. But don't be scared: you are not alone. We're all, more or less, going through this process.

Comment: Indeed, “All aluminum can” means _Tutto l'alluminio può_. ;)